# What is unclear here please?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Farmbitrage: Fixed starting rating for chess960 causes loophole to easily get 2000 rating?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41447/farmbitrage-fixed-starting-rating-for-chess960-causes-loophole-to-easily-get-20)

Answer (score 13):

Many of your questions have the same problem. You need to get to the point and keep your questions short and focused.

Find a way to express yourself without 12 separate sub-points, links to multiple YouTube videos, and linking to eleven different stackexchange questions. And don't waste words arguing against hypothetical answers you haven't seen yet. Your question should not be so long that it requires disclaimers about what parts of it are necessary or optional.

To be clear: it is not *just* the elaboration takes away from the focus and clarity of your questions. Your entire style is not focused on brevity and conciseness. The more you say, the less it is clear what aspects are important.

Comment: ' short and focused' --> there is already an 'in short' there. If the elaboration is problematic, then why not ignore the elaboration?

Comment: @BCLC if you can make the question with the "in short" part, then you can get rid of the rest of it. Please remember that Stack Exchange's objective is not only answering the specific question a user is posing, but rather creating a repository of knowledge that can be useful for people reading your question and its answers in the future